# Goodman GM880804BNBA ignitor will not stay on

Tags: hvac, furnace

I have a Goodman furnace model **# GM880804BNBA** that stopped working.

- The ignitor fires and three seconds later the gas valve clicks, and the ignitor and inducer shut off before the gas starts to flow.
- I cleaned the flame sensor and checked it for cracks. I also checked the ignitor for continuity, and it shows 80 Ohms.
- I checked the pressure switch, and it shows 0 resistance. Then, I jumped the gas valve directly to 12v transformer. Gas flowed just fine.
- The red light on the control board stays lit through the entire process and does not blink.

Could it be the control board or something else. Please assist.

Comment: Gas flowed but without safety on.  The Flame sensor has to report >700mV otherwise the gas and ignitor will stop.

Comment: So, are you saying that the flame sensor is bad even without seeing any defects?

Comment: I did not say that, just gave you the number (mV) which you can messure,

Comment: How do I check it there is no flame?

Comment: Heat it up with heat gun

Comment: @Ruskes The flame sensing rod used in most (north american?) furnaces these days is not a thermal device. It's just a piece of stainless steel wire. It can't be tested with a heat gun. Perhaps you're thinking of a thermocouple or thermopile.

Comment: @GregHill interesting, so how does a piece of wire reports flame on

Comment: @Ruskes [Google how does a flame sensor work on a furnace](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+a+flame+sensor+work+on+a+furnace) or [flame rectification](https://www.google.com/search?q=flame+rectification) The wire doesn't report anything; it's simply an electrode. When flame is present a few microamps of current flow between the sensing rod and the burners (ie furnace case). This current does not flow when the flame is extinguished. A circuit in the control board detects this difference and determines the flame status.

Answer (score 1):

If the ignitor glows yellow-orange for several seconds then it's fine.

It's too early to know whether your flame sensor has a problem. The furnace control confirms that the flame sensor indicates "no flame" before the ignition sequence begins, but the sensor won't be checked again until the gas valve has opened and the gas (should be) ignited. Yours isn't getting that far along. There's no need to tinker with the flame sensor until/unless there's reason to suspect it has a problem.

A furnace is equipped with (usually two) flame rollout switch(es). These are wired in series with the gas valve so that even if the control wants to turn on the gas these safety switches can prevent it. They're often manually resetable. Trace the conductors from the gas valve. They should lead to one or two switches looking something like the photo below (from [www.repairclinic.com](http://www.repairclinic.com)). Press the button on the back of the switch while listening and feeling for it to click -- this will indicate that it was indeed tripped and now is reset.

[image: rollout switch]

After checking/resetting the rollout switches try running the furnace again.

Flame rollout switches should "never" trip. If you find that one of yours did trip, or in other words if the reset method described above gets it running again, then a qualified person should check the furnace to hopefully determine what caused the trip and ensure that the furnace is operating safely and correctly.